# Probability of getting 3 different CDS from 3 different boxes.

Tags: probability

Boxes of Cheerios contain a CD.  There are 3 different CD's.  A person buys 3 boxes of cheerios.  Of course there is the possibility that there will be duplicates among the prizes. What is the probability that the person will get three different CD's?

Comment: Need more info to solve this.

Comment: @mathtastic such as?

Comment: Should we assume that there are an equal amount of each CD distributed among the boxes? What if there are 5 times as many of CD A as there are of CD B etc. That is, what is the probability of obtaining each CD when we open a box.

Answer (score 1):

You buy your first box. There will be CD 1,2 or 3 inside. The next box have to have a diffierent CD inside. The probability for this event is 2/3, because one of three CDs shouldn´t be inside this box.

If you buy the third box, there have to be a different CD inside again. You already have 2 different CDs. Thus the box have to have one specific CD. What is the probability for that ?

If you have this probability, then you have to multiply the two probabilities to get the probability that you get 3 different CDs.